# How do I read only the second line from this char buffer in c?

Tags: c, char

```
  char buf[256];
    ssize_t bytes_read; 
    /* Read some data from the client.  */
    bytes_read = read (fd, buf, sizeof (buf) - 1);
    buf[bytes_read] = '\0';
    printf ("Buffer %s", buf);
```

This is the output display.

GET /index.html HTTP/1.1

Host: 127.0.0.1:8080

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-EncoMy hostname: ubuntu
FILE : 58HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2015 15:56:02

Server: Host server

Last-Modified: Tue, 17 Feb 2015 00:19:56

Content-type: text/html

Content-length: 58

I only need to store the "127.0.0.1".
Please kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: Show more code. What have you tried ?

Comment: this my code. I tried sscanf (buf, "\r\n%s",host);

Answer (score 1):

Reference for c string handling library: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte)

What you seem to want to do is commonly called "splitting the string".
In your case by line so you will split at line end characters.
Note depending on your input this might be "\n" or "\r\n"

The function you need is [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)
The link includes a very nice example on how to split a string.

You just need to split by "\n" for example:

```
    char *token = strtok(input, "\n");
    while(token) {
        printf(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
```

Rather than printf you can now save your lines one by one for later use or you can keep a counter and just process the second line and then exit if that is all you need.

Comment: it's doesn't work here. It display "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0 ...." onward.

Comment: Read the last part about "rather than printf"... I gave you the tools to implement a solution, I don't think the idea is that I write your program for you. Also you changed your question since I've posted this...